# ElasticSearch: range date with fields inside fields

Tags: json, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have an Issue that I need to wrote a elasticsearch query that give me what I look for,
first of all here is one item of my JSON object in db that query looking into:

```
{
  "data": {
    "circuit": {
      "version": "2.12.2",
      "createdOn": "2020-02-04T10:38:11.282",
      "expirationDate": "2020-02-06T05:50:00.000",
      "expiredSoonNotification": false
    }
  },
  "createdDate": "2020-02-04T10:38:11.282"
}
```

What I need is to get all Items that accept this condition:

**now < "data.circuit.expirationDate" < ("data.circuit.expirationDate" - "createdDate")/10 + now**

meaning : I need to get all items that there expirationDate is less 10% from now
I hope that I explained my issue cause I don't know how to use fields inside **lt** og **gt**

something I did until now like that, but not working :

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "range": {
                  "data.circuit.expirationDate": {
                    "gt": "now",
                    "lt": ("data.circuit.expirationDate" - "createdDate")/10 + now
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "createdDate": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Thank You

Comment: what is your mapping and what have you tried so far? Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @ibexit I added what I tried until now

Comment: just to be sure, is this the formula for searched docs: `expirationDate > now && expirationDate < (expirationDate - createdDate)/10 + now`?

Comment: @ibexit Yes exactly

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do math referencing other fields in a `range`-query. You would need to encode your logic in a `script`-query using the Elasticsearch "painless" scripting-language. `Script`-queries are significantly slower than other queries, as the script needs to get executed for every single document. You can limit the number of documents for which the script gets executed by breaking up the logic into 2 parts:

1. `"data.circuit.expirationDate" > now`
2. `"data.circuit.expirationDate" < 
   (("data.circuit.expirationDate" - "createdDate")/10 + now)`

Your query structure would need to look like this (Pseudo-code):

```
"query": {
  "bool": {
    "must": { "script": "data.circuit.expirationDate" < ("data.circuit.expirationDate" - "createdDate")/10 + now) }
    "filter": { "range": "data.circuit.expirationDate" > now }
  }
}
```

You also should consider whether you really need precision down to millisecond-level. Performance-wise it would be much better to round `now` to a more granular unit (e.g. now/s for second-level granularity).

Pre-calculating `("data.circuit.expirationDate" - "createdDate")/10` and storing the calculated result directly in your document would furthermore increase query-performance significantly.